# How to emulate ISNOTNULL()

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to do the following in mysq?

```
SELECT SUM(ISNOTNULL(myfield)), SUM(myfield) FROM table
```

I know I can do `ISNULL()` in mysql but how would I do the opposite?

Comment: What do you want to do? Count how many times the field is not null?

Comment: @juergend that is correct

Comment: Just use `COUNT`... it will only count the non-null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `sum` wich a condition

```
SELECT SUM(myfield is not null), SUM(myfield) 
FROM your_table
```

or use `count` which counts only non-null values

```
SELECT count(myfield), SUM(myfield) 
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(myfield) FROM table WHERE myfield IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Please see updated question: I cannot change my WHERE statement.

Comment: Sure you can.  Add "AND myfield IS NOT NULL" at the end.